# Syntax error on elif in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create bash script that allows me to copy files into a temporary file while putting it in caps.  I'm getting an error:

```
"Syntax error near unexpected token <<then>>" on line 26.
```

Do you guys have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Apparently the start of my message hasn't made it into the post but it says hello.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

ok=true

function majuscule(){

ficTemp=$(/usr/bin/mktemp)
echo -e "Le contenu sera transferer dans le fichier temporaire $ficTemp"

for i in "$@" ; do
     tr [:lower:] [:upper:] < $i > $ficTemp
done
}
if (( $# == 0 )) ; then
    echo -e "Vous devez entrer au moins un parametre">&2
    ok=false
fi   

for i in "$@" ; do
    if [[ ! -e "$i" ]] ; then
        echo -e "Le fichier $i n'est pas permit en écriture ">&2
        ok=false
    elif [[ ! -r "$i" ]] ; then
        echo -e "Le fichier $i n'est pas permit en lecture">&2
        ok=false
    elif [[ ! -f "$i" ]] ; then
        echo -e "Le fichier $i n'est pas ordinaire">&2
        ok=false
    elif [[ -x "$i" ]] ; then
        echo -e "Le fichier $i est permis en execution">&2
        ok=false
    elif [[ ! -s "$i" ]] ; then
        echo -e "Le fichier $i est vide">&2
        ok=false
    fi
done
if [[ $ok=false ]] ; then
     exit 1
else 
    majuscule
fi
```

Comment: fix your var assignments. No spaces around `=` signs allowed! ; -) (elif s look OK, unless there is something really strange in your `"$i"` value). Good luck.

Comment: In addition ... this: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: oops, and `ficTemp=$/usr/bin/mktemp` ? You probably mean `ficTemp=$(/usr/bin/mktemp)`. Good luck.

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Don't make us play 20 questions.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Your help has fixed lots of issues I hadn't seen. I'm getting the error "Syntax error near unexpected token <<then>>" on line 26. Thanks again.

Comment: `ok = false` is still wrong (line 16)

Comment: You are not using the bash interpreter you claim to.  It may be defaulting to .sh or maybe even csh or ksh.  After I fixed up your 3 or 4 syntax errors, bash reveals your if/elseif code to be correct.  Put this command in your script and tell us what it outputs, `ps h -p $$ -o args='' | cut -f1 -d' '`  the first step in identifying bugs is to know what language you are writing in.

Comment: It says i'm running bash which should be right. Right ?

Comment: For your shebang line to be recognized, `#!` must be the very first 2 bytes of the file - in your code, there's a _leading space_.

Comment: By the way -- unless you have a specific reason to use the `-e` argument to echo, don't.

Comment: (...and if you _do_ have a specific reason to use `echo -e`, perhaps you should use printf instead; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX echo command spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: ..._also_, the `"$@"` inside your function is not the same as `"$@"` in global scope, so right now, you're never passing the function any arguments. `majescule "$@"` would pass all your command's arguments through to the function, if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: (...but what's the point of overwriting a temporary file over and over in a loop, each time destroying the content you wrote in the iteration immediately prior?)

Comment: Anyhow - before asking a question like this, you should remove any/all code unrelated to the error -- if you don't know what isn't related, take something out and see if the error still happens; if it doesn't, leave it out, if it does, put it back! More guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the help. The  "<<>>"  is just a translation problem since my linux is in french and those are french quotes. And you're right about the -e. I erased them. Thank you for all the advices ill try to fix this. This is a wonderful community.